# Add multiple lib directories to my java WebApp

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

I want to organize my library directory of my java webapp.
I want to load custom jar files from custom lib directories for a specific webapp.

Consider directory structure to be this:

`myapp/WEB-INF/lib`

`myapp/WEB-INF/dependencylib`

I don't want to copy the dependency jar files to the WEB-INF/lib.
It would make it difficult for me to maintain the dependencies if I do that.

What are the configuration changes needed to add the dependency library packed with the webapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such configuration parameter. You must put all your web application's libraries in `WEB-INF\lib` to be loaded automatically (as per Servlet spec).
If you don't want to do that (and of course not put the libraries inside the shared libs of tomcat) then your only option is to write you own custom [Web application ClassLoader](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/loader.html) using the `context.xml` which besides the libraries in `WEB-INF\lib` (and the classes in `WEB-INF\classes`) would load your dependent jars in `WEB-INF/dependencylib`.

This guy [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/extending-tomcat-webapploader) seems to have an example of his loader